# How to access my facebook name in my website after logging through facebook?

Tags: facebook

I created a .aspx page with login button in it.
I register my website and also got AppID.
Then i granted basic permissions also.

Finally i want to get my facebook name after pressing login and page will redirect to my page only.
So what should i write in my .aspx page???

Please help with necessary steps.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the javascript sdk you can load the me object :

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

After you get the name you can redirect.

Cheers!